# Why Python multiprocessing slowed down my function execution?

Tags: python, multithreading, performance, graph, multiprocessing

I am writing code for the MinCut graph problem in python on Ubuntu, after proving correctness with single thread implementation I am trying to speed things up using multithreading/multiprocessing but my code slows down.
I noticed a strange behavior , when I use 2 threads the time taken for the algorithm function execution doubles compared to single thread implementation canceling out the gain of having 2 threads and resulting actually in a slow down due to the multiprocessing overhead and I can't know really why , the only possible explanation I had that I have a single core processor but this is not the case as my laptop has an Intel® Core™ i5-6200U CPU @ 2.30GHz × 4

**Numbers**

Single Thread : iteration time (mostly run time of randomContraction function) is on average 200 ms

```
time allocation, rand sel time 0.00 collapse time 0.12 self loops time 0.08
iteration # 6882 of 211931 took time 0.20 Graph creation time 0.00 alg run time 0.20 elasped time 1439.17 total time 42797.71 progress 3.36 cut = 9
```

Using 2 threads `from multithreading import Thread` : 2 parallel iteration times on average is 470 ms as function speed slowed down from 200 ms to about 470 ms , as I am waiting for join so will take worst case

```
time allocation, rand sel time 0.00 collapse time 0.22 self loops time 0.17
time allocation, rand sel time 0.00 collapse time 0.25 self loops time 0.16
iteration # 26 of 211931 took time 0.47 Graph creation time 0.05 alg run time 0.42 elasped time 6.62 total time 50250.92 progress 0.01 cut = None
```

Using 2 processes `from multiprocessing import Process` : 2 parallel iterations times on average is 460 ms as function speed slowed down from 200 ms to about 460 ms , as I am waiting for join so will take worst case .

```
time allocation, rand sel time 0.00 collapse time 0.24 self loops time 0.16
time allocation, rand sel time 0.00 collapse time 0.24 self loops time 0.16
iteration # 48 of 211931 took time 0.46 Graph creation time 0.05 alg run time 0.41 elasped time 10.96 total time 48907.02 progress 0.02 cut = None
```

My expectations were that 2 iterations would take 200 ms or slightly more doubling the speed of my code but seems that now randomContraction function run time has doubled so negating the effect of parallelism

**Code**

I removed the lines for calculating and logging time to reduce clutter

```
def randomContraction(G, cut, i):

    while G.numNodes() > 2 :
        edgeIndex = G.randEdgeIndex()
        G.collapse(edgeIndex)
        G.removeSelfLoops()

    cut[i] = G.cut()
    return 


def kragerMinCut(list):

    num_threads = 2
    elapsed = 0
    n = len(list)
    orig = Graph(list)
    iterations = int(n*n*math.log(n))
    threads = [None] * num_threads
    G = [None] * num_threads
    cut = [None] * iterations
    i = 0

    while i < iterations:

        for j in range(len(G)):
            G[j] = copy.deepcopy(orig)

        for j in range(len(threads)):
            threads[j] = Process(target=randomContraction, args=(G[j], cut, j+i))
            threads[j].start()

        for j in range(len(threads)):
            threads[j].join()


        i += num_threads

    print(cut)
    return min(cut)
```

Comment: The slow-down is probably due to start-up costs. If you were working with a longer running program there would probably be speed-ups

Comment: would you suggest that instead of making a thread for a single iteration is to take many iterations (10 for example) and consequently minimizing startup cost ?

Comment: You know what they say about [premature optimization](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization) now don't you ? ;)

Comment: @user2386276 This seems contradicting with my measurements because they show that runtime for internal components of randomContraction increase , if you take a look at single thread impl vs multithreaded collapse function runtime doubled and also removeSelfloops runtime doubled

Comment: @alfasin looks like an interesting read, I read a few lines . If the general idea is that I am trying to do an unnecessary optimization then my reply would be that this program will take around 12 hours to complete . So optimization is really necessary.

Comment: @Ahmed as user23... already explained, threads/processes don't come "free", they have a "cost" (additional CPU, memory, overhead of loading the stack and etc). In order for tradeoff to be worthy you want the added-value to be bigger than the cost. In your case when each execution takes a few milliseconds it seems that the cost is bigger. If you can create less processes and have each process do more work - the tradeoff might be better.

Comment: I am not a python expert - but you seem to create processes not threads. Those are much more expensive in setup than threads.

Comment: @alfasin looks reasonable . I will try a global parallelism approach and see results (i.e split total work over num of threads)

Comment: In general, when using multiprocessing, you should make sure that those processes run for a long time. Your timing difference is in milliseconds which is an area of time where multiprocessing will always cost more.